# How to estimate the value of a column for each month from a table having date data in mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a mysql table 'data_table' in mysql with around 5 million records like:

```
  ------------------------------------------------------------------
    serial  |   month from  |   month to         |       consumption

    123         2012-01-01     2013-01-10                  200
    111         2012-12-28     2013-01-29                  324
    123         2013-01-11     2013-05-13                  1675
    111         2013-01-30     2013-02-16                  200
    391         2012-12-28     2013-02-27                  113
    123         2013-05-14     2013-05-28                  234
    123         2013-05-29     2013-06-05                  53
    123         2013-08-01     2013-09-26                  783 
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How to find estimated  value for consumption for each month like:
consumption for January(2013-01-01 to 2013-01-31)  = ..., for February = .... for each serial.

The result should be like: Estimated value for January, 2013

```
Serial     Month        year     Estimated_Consumption
 123       January      2013              472.5
```

Like this the code should be able to list all the months, years and the estimated value for corresponding Serial number.

The logic behind the estimation for January for serial 123 is:

```
Total number of days in January = 31, 
Consumption for the first 10 days = 200
Consumption for the next 21 days = number of days for January in (2013-01-11, 2013-05-13)
* consumption per day for the period (2013-01-11, 2013-05-13)
Adding both these I get the consumption for January =  472.5
```

Comment: Define "*estimated value*".

Comment: Estimated as in, if we are considering the value for January, then, combining consumption values for time periods which have January data, for example here for serial '123' there are three time periods which has January data, the solution should be able to split consumption into individual months, and combine all of January values, thus estimating the consumption for January.

Comment: Please provide the desired result based on your sample data.

Comment: Added logic and sample of how desired result should be.

Comment: Can you please add your logic for # **123** (the same serial number) for **May** and **July**, 2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thank you all for replying. I figured out how to do this.
For this I use a calendar table as explained in this link: http://www.brianshowalter.com/calendar_tables

Further, I added another column to the data table, a consumption per day table. 
For example:

```
    premise         date_from       date_to     consumption     consumption per day
    111             12/13/2012      1/22/2013       200         4.88
    222             12/17/2012      1/12/2013       300         11.11
    111             1/23/2013       4/20/2013       200         2.27
    222             1/13/2013       1/20/2013       300         37.5
    111             4/23/2013       5/10/2013       200         11.11
```

The query is:

```
SELECT id,
        date_from as bill_start_date,
        theYear as Year,
        MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(theMonth, '%m')) as month,  # use theMonth for displaying the month as a number
        DaysOnBill,
        TotalDaysInTheMonth,
        sum(perDayConsumption *  DaysOnBill) as EstimatedConsumption 
    FROM
    ( 
     SELECT
        id,
        date_from,
        theYear,
        theMonth,  # use theMonth for displaying the month as a number
        COUNT(*) AS DaysOnBill,
        TotalDaysInTheMonth, 
        perDayConsumption
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
            c.id,
            c.date_from as date_from,
            ct.dt,
            y AS theYear,
            month AS theMonth,
            DAY(LAST_DAY(ct.dt)) as TotalDaysInTheMonth,
            perDayConsumption
        FROM
            consumption AS c
            INNER JOIN
            calendar_table AS ct
                ON ct.dt >= c.date_from
                    AND ct.dt<= c.date_to
        ) AS allDates
    GROUP BY
        id,
        date_from,
        theYear,
        theMonth ) AS estimates
GROUP BY
        id,
        theYear,
        theMonth;
```

Here the calendar table is a separate table which lists month, year and dates among other things.